# javafx-maven-plugin Updates Wrong Folder

Tags: java, javafx-8, maven-plugin

There are two different javafx applications using `javafx-maven-plugin` to generate native windows installer. In both applications the installers are generated and can be seen at `target\jfx\native` .

When the first app installer setup installation process is started, setup shows files are copied in `C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\CooperativeERP`.

The problem is when the second application installation process is started it goes to the same folder and updates some files which makes first app installed unusable.

Plugin Maven `XML` is as follows:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>re.iprocu.coperativeerp.MainApp</mainClass>

                <bundleArguments>
                    <licenseFile>termsOfService.rtf</licenseFile>
                </bundleArguments>
                <additionalAppResources>src/main/additionalAppResources</additionalAppResources><!-- name does not matter, it's just some folder :D -->
                <!-- DO SHOW DEBUG-OUTPUT -->
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- required before build-native -->
                    <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>create-native</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-native</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

What should i do to make the two setup install as different application and not to get to each others way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that zen java maven plugin uses a `Main` class package as unique identifier for application, and in this particular case both application had the same package name.

Changing package for one application solved my problem.